# .GIT branching strategy: Shared branch being updated while another dev is in the middle of merging?

Tags: git, merge, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

Our .git branching strategy is as follows:

- Each developer has a _dev branch (e.g. john_dev)

  - Each dev has their own branch because "Isolate just John's changes in QA so we can test them independently" is a fairly common use case for this team, and each dev having their own dev branch seems like the easiest way to do that (they can just build a non-prod artifact from their own branch with no extra effort at all)
- When you want to merge your features with others: fetch/pull remotes, then merge the UAT branch into your _dev branch (we encourage devs to do this frequently regardless)
- **resolve any merge conflicts** (sitting down with the other dev if needed) and commit/push them
- do a quick local build to check for any issues
- Checkout the UAT and merge your dev branch into UAT.
- Push to UAT remote
- Triggers a build to UAT servers from the UAT branch

The point at which this process seems too cumbersome is: Merges with merge conflicts (naturally) take much longer than merges without. sometimes by the time a developer has merged the shared branch ('UAT' in our case) with their new code, resolved conflicts, and is ready to checkout/merge into the shared branch...another developer has already committed more code there. and so their local copy of the shared branch is 'behind' and so they'll have to merge a second time, one way or another.

How do dev teams normally handle this? Is merging a second time because the upstream has changed fairly standard?

Is it just the fact that we're using per-dev develop branches that makes this process feel cumbersome?

[image: My attempt at MS painting what I mean, if my description was confusing]

Comment: Better strategy is to *rebase* development branches against upstream (`UAT` in your case). `git pull --rebase origin UAT`.

Comment: @0andriy - in terms of having a clean upstream commit history? Wouldn't repeating rebase/merge and resolving conflicts twice still be necessary?

Comment: In terms of having clean history in *development* branches. What you put in item 2 in your list above is so called *back merges* and they are ugly.

Comment: I didn't get where you see repeating resolving conflicts twice (or more times)? Each rebase will  be either clean or with **new** conflicts if the same file had been touched by upstream and developer.